# which countries have been having unprecedented air travel in last 4-5 years.

Tags: air-travel, international-travel

I looked at http://www.statista.com/statistics/193533/growth-of-global-air-traffic-passenger-demand/ which just listed how much aggregate growth in air travel from 2005 to 2015. Does anybody know or can find out :-

a. The countries which have recorded the highest jumps in international air travel, this is people traveling from host country to different countries.  ( I would guess China and then somewhere down India)

b. The countries which have recorded the highest jumps in short-term tourist in-flows. I would not add long-term immigration as that has different implications and probably would not impact airlines and air-travel as much as people going for business or leisure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.